# Only when reloading the page, the scroll bar does not go to the top after clicking the button to scroll to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say the scrollbar is located in the middle of a div that has an oversize table of data. Now if I reload page, and click the button has code the following code:

```
$("#loadTableData").on("click", function() {
    loadData();
    $("#divTable").scrollTop(0,0);
});
```

The scrollbar does not go to the top as I expected. But if I click it again (after reloading the table data), it does go to the top.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: It is not the reason for you problem, but `scrollTop` takes only one argument.

Comment: Tried swapping the order of those two commands?

Comment: If that doesn't work, does the `loadData()` function call ajax? If so, add the `scrollTop` to that ajax `success()` or afterward. Expand the function to include id to make it universal.

Comment: Same problem after swapping and placing the scrollTop inside ajax call success..

Comment: I only see this problem in FireFox and not in IE..